# Multiple Focus in EditText on ListView row

Tags: android

I have a edittext for each row in ListView on android.
Each EditText have a event click to execute a specific system requirement.
The problem is when i click for example on edittext in first row, the sixth row also receive focus and the click event.

This is my FocusHandler to set the event to clicked editText

private class FocusHandler implements OnFocusChangeListener {

```
    @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasFocus) {

        Log.d("PRODUTO", "ON FOCUS "+hasFocus+" "+view);
        if (!hasFocus) {
            if (focusedEditText != null) {
                focusedEditText.removeTextChangedListener(textWatcher);
                if (focusedEditText.getText().toString().equals("")) {
                    focusedEditText.setText(temp);
                }//end if
            }//end if
        } else {
            EditText et = (EditText) view;
            focusedEditText = et;
            temp = focusedEditText.getText().toString();
            focusedEditText.setText("");
            focusedEditText.addTextChangedListener(textWatcher);

        }// end else

        //focusedEditText = null;

    }// end method

}// end class
```

Comment: could you post the getView code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, sure... Thanks

@Override
    public void bindView(final View view, final Context context, final Cursor cursor) {

```
        LinearLayout llDescricao = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_lldescricao);
        LinearLayout llComponentes = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_llcomponentes);
        LinearLayout llImage = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_llimage);
        LinearLayout llQtVolume = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_llqtVolume);
        LinearLayout llQtTroca = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_llqttroca);
        RelativeLayout rlProdutos = (RelativeLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.RelativeLayout_produtos);
        LinearLayout ll3 = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_llcomponentes_3);
        LinearLayout llCorGrade = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_llcorgrade);
        LinearLayout llCor = (LinearLayout) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_llcor);
        rlProdutos.removeView(llImage);

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();

        holder.spCor = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.produtos_spCor);
        holder.spGrade = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.produtos_spGrade);
        TextView tvCod = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.produtos_tvCod);
        TextView tvDescricao = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_tvDescricao);
        ImageView ivFoto = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_ivProduto);

        tvCod.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex("produto_codigo")));
        tvDescricao.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex("produto_descricao")));

        holder.etQtd = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_etQuantidade);

            holder.btnMaisUm = (Button) view
                    .findViewById(R.id.produtos_btnMais);

            holder.btnMaisUm.setTag(holder.etQtd);

            holder.btnMaisUm.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    Log.d("PRODUTO", "TRIGGER "+teste++);
                    Button button = (Button) v;
                    EditText et = (EditText) button.getTag();
                    et.requestFocus();
                    String qtdText = et.getText().toString();

                    if (qtdText.equals("")) {
                        qtdText = temp;
                    }// end if
                    float qtd = Float.parseFloat(qtdText) + 1;
                    et.setText(String.valueOf(qtd));

                }// end onClick
            });

        holder.etDesconto = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_etDesconto);
        // PEGAR DESCONTO VINDO DO PEDIDO ENVIADO PRA CA
        holder.etDesconto.setText(String.valueOf(pedido.getPdesconto()));
        holder.etDesconto.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusHandler);
        int editaDesconto = Integer.valueOf(prop
                .getProperty("config.edita_desconto"));
        if (editaDesconto == 0) {
            holder.etDesconto.setInputType(0);
            holder.etDesconto.setEnabled(false);
        }

        /**
         * CALCULAR UNITARIO ET UNITARIO
         */
        holder.etUnitario = (EditText) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_etUnitario);
        holder.etUnitario.setOnFocusChangeListener(focusHandler);
        int editaUnitario = Integer.valueOf(prop
                .getProperty("config.edita_unitario"));
        if (editaUnitario == 0) {
            holder.etUnitario.setInputType(0);
            holder.etUnitario.setEnabled(false);
        }// end if

        /**
         * TEXTVIEW TOTAL
         */
        holder.tvTotal = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.produtos_tvTotal);

        holder.etQtd.setTag(R.id.etQuantidadeTroca, holder.etQtdTroca);
        holder.etQtd.setTag(R.id.spCorKey, holder.spCor);
        holder.etQtd.setTag(R.id.spGradeKey, holder.spGrade);
        holder.etQtd.setTag(R.id.etDescontoKey, holder.etDesconto);
        holder.etQtd.setTag(R.id.etUnitarioKey, holder.etUnitario);
        holder.etQtd.setTag(R.id.etUnitarioTabelaKey,
                holder.etUnitarioTabela);
        holder.etQtd.setTag(R.id.tvTotalKey, holder.tvTotal);
        holder.etQtd.setTag(R.id.produtoIdKey,
                cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("_id")));
        holder.etQtd.setOnFocusChangeListener(new FocusHandler());
        holder.etDesconto.setTag(holder.etQtd);
        holder.etUnitario.setTag(holder.etQtd);
        holder.uuidProduto = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex("produto_uuid"));


}// end bindView
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set new `FocusHandler()` on all your `setOnFocusChangeListener`. The member `focusedEditText` of your `FocusHandler class` can be modified by `holder.etDesconto` and `holder.etUnitario` of each row because they share the same object `focusHandler`.

Comment: Thanks for help but it seems that a problem with the render of the listview when it is scrolled, because i've implemented a simple extended base adapter and the same problem was happening.
Note: I did not ViewHolder pattern in this test